# Keeping UITableView scrolling smoothly during long calculations

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uitableview

What is the best way to keep a UITableView scrolling smoothly if the contents of each cell require heavy calculation? For example:

```
#define maxN 40

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return maxN;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    //customization
    int row = indexPath.row;
    int fib = [self fib:row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", fib];

    return cell;
}

- (int)fib:(int)n
{
    return (n<=2 ? 1 : [self fib:n-1] + [self fib:n-2]);
}
```

This works fine for a maxN up to about 30. With values larger than that the table view will stall while calculating the large numbers.

I know the solution has to do with async calculation, but how would you set that up to keep the UI smooth?

UPDATE:
Here are the updated methods.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"FibIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    [self configureCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

-(void)configureCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self.fibResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] != [NSNull null]) {
        // apply cached result
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.fibTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [(NSNumber*)[self.fibResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];

        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
        NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
        int fib = [self fib:row];

        //cache the result
        [self.fibResults replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fib]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.fibTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        });
    });
}
```

The good news is that the table scrolls smoothly. The bad news is that the cells are populated with random values, instead of the correct 1,1,2,3,5,8 etc. order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perform these types of operations in the background thread, then dispatch back to the main thread to update the table view cell. The trick is that the cell may have been reused by then, so you need to call `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` instead of referencing the cell. You should also be caching your results in a dictionary or some other form of memoization.

```
-(void)configureCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (haveCachedResult) {
        // apply cached result
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH) ^{
        // perform long-running work. Cache result.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: A few more thoughts: (1) long-running calculations can be performed and cached in the background completely separately from your UITableView while your app's not busy - NSOperationQueue provides a good interface for this sort of thing.  (2) This approach is more complex if your cells have dynamic heights because you can't return the height asynchronously.  In this case, height is the first thing you should calculate.  (3) If the count or order of your items might change, you'll need a synchronization point. Look into `NSLock` and `@synchronized` if this is the case.

Comment: What is updateCellsAtIndexPaths:animation? This is not documented in UITableView.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing - Where do I put the call to configureCellAtIndexPath?

Comment: Please see the updated post. I still can't get the right values to display. Something must be wrong with the way I'm using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: The issue is cell re-use. Before configuring your cell, try resetting the values used in the text field to `@""`.

Comment: Getting rid of configureCellAtIndexPath: and just doing the if/else within cellForRowAtIndexPath: fixed the problem.